# ExtJs Combox not rendering correctly

Tags: extjs

I am trying the get a combox in a grid which select something in the editor function. But the rendering value is 0 each time. After saving it works correctly.

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.Order.view.detail.BackPosition', {
override: 'Shopware.apps.Order.view.detail.Position',

initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;
    me.mdsupplierStore = Ext.create('Shopware.apps.Order.store.MDSupplier').load();
    me.callParent(arguments);

},

getColumns: function(grid) {
    var me          = this;

    var col     = me.callOverridden(arguments);
    var md_supplier =   {};
    grid.mdsupplierStore = me.mdsupplierStore;

    var MDSupplier= {
        header: 'Lieferant',
        dataIndex: 'md_supplier',
        flex:2,
        renderer: me.supplierColumn,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            editable: false,
            queryMode: 'local',
            allowBlank: false,
            store: grid.mdsupplierStore,
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'id',

        }

    };


    col =  Ext.Array.insert(col, 9, [MDSupplier]);
    return col;
},

supplierColumn: function(value, metaData, rowRecord) {

    var me = this;
    console.log(value);
   //value is 0 when I click the editor combobox <---
},
```

});

Model:

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.Order.model.MDSupplier', {
    extend:'Shopware.data.Model',

idProperty : 'id',

fields:[

    { name : 'id', type: 'int'},
    { name : 'name', type: 'string'}
]
```

});

Store:

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.Order.store.MDSupplier',{
configure: function() {
    return { controller: 'MDSupplier' };
},
/**
 * Define that this component is an extension of the Ext.data.Store
 */
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

/**
 * Auto load the store after the component
 * is initialized
 * @boolean
 */
autoLoad: false,

/**
 * Define the used model for this store
 * @string
 */
model: 'Shopware.apps.Order.model.MDSupplier',

proxy : {
    type : 'ajax',
    url: '/backend/MDSupplier/load',

    reader:{
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        totalProperty: 'total'
    }
}
```

});

Can anybody tell me, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Since your values come from a store, please provide the data you load into the store.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The processing of the data was wrong, so the field was everytime NULL